# What does "which" mean in this sentence (math)?

Tags: meaning-in-context, mathematics

> For the positive integers a, b, c, and d, a is half of b, which is one-third of c. The value of d is three times the value of c.

Does this mean that a=b/2, and a=c/3, or does this mean that a=b/2, and b=c/3?

Comment: I'd say it's ambiguous. "Which" could refer to "b", or it could refer to "half of B".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a pronoun usually refers to the closest possible preceding nominal. In this case, the relative pronoun "which" refers to the previous word, the noun "b". Thus, b = c/3.